# Create scatterplot for different conditions with points and colors in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I have a data frame like this :

```
chr     start       end   Variant A      Variant B     LMM_SE LMM_pvalue 
chr1  10000000  10199999 -0.0125342653  -0.004448612 0.01333641  0.5446332 
chr1 100000000 100199999 -0.0086324343   0.006084511 0.01950774  0.4510183 
chr1 100050000 100249999 -0.0020966126   0.014495167 0.02198149  0.4507781   
chr1 100100000 100299999  0.0013000540   0.007365210 0.01830545  0.7405400   
chr1 100150000 100349999 -0.0002933631   0.004637209 0.02355737  0.8343087  
chr1 100200000 100399999  0.0091093560   0.008424283 0.01846987  0.9704298  
chr1 100250000 100449999  0.0060152176   0.046687423 0.03062414  0.1849628
```

I would like to create a scatter plot in R to compare with different colors and symbols the values of variant A and B like this :

[image]

Comment: try `plot(data$\`Variant A\`, data$\`Variant B\`, col=ifelse(data$\`Variant A\` > 0.2, 2, 1))`

Answer (score 2):

You can define colors and point characters using `ifelse`.

Sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  Variant_A = rnorm(1000),
  Variant_B = runif(1000)
)
```

For example:

```
plot(df$Variant_B~df$Variant_A,
     col = ifelse(df$Variant_B <= 0.5, "blue", "deeppink"),
     pch = ifelse(df$Variant_A >= 0.5, 1, 0))
```

[image]